# How flatMap API contract transforms Optional input to Non Optional result?

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming, option-type

This is the contract of flatMap in Swift 3.0.2

```
public struct Array<Element> : RandomAccessCollection, MutableCollection {
    public func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
}
```

If I take an Array of `[String?]` flatMap returns [String]

```
let albums = ["Fearless", nil, "Speak Now", nil, "Red"]
let result = albums.flatMap { $0 }
type(of: result) 
// Array<String>.Type
```

Here `ElementOfResult` becomes `String`, why not `String?` ? How is the generic type system able to strip out the Optional part from the expression?

Answer (score 4):

As you're using the identity transform `{ $0 }`, the compiler will infer that `ElementOfResult?` (the result of the transform) is equivalent to `Element` (the argument of the transform). In this case, `Element` is `String?`, therefore `ElementOfResult?` == `String?`. There's no need for optional promotion here, so `ElementOfResult` can be inferred to be `String`.

Therefore `flatMap(_:)` in this case returns a `[String]`.

Internally, this conversion from the closure's return of `ElementOfResult?` to `ElementOfResult` is simply done by conditionally unwrapping the optional, and if successful, the unwrapped value is appended to the result. You can see the [exact implementation here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L709).

---

As an addendum, note that [as Martin points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213656/how-flatmap-api-contract-transforms-optional-input-to-non-optional-result#comment71588951_42213785), closure bodies only participate in type inference when they're *single-statement* closures (see [this related bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1570)). The reasoning for this was given by Jordan Rose [in this mailing list discussion](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002583.html):

> Swift's type inference is currently statement-oriented, so there's no easy way to do [multiple-statement closure] inference. This is at least partly a compilation-time concern: Swift's type system allows many more possible conversions than, say, Haskell or OCaml, so solving the types for an entire multi-statement function is not a trivial problem, possibly not a tractable problem.

This means that for closures with multiple statements that are passed to methods such as `map(_:)` or `flatMap(_:)` (where the result type is a generic placeholder), you'll have to explicitly annotate the return type of the closure, or the method return itself.

For example, this doesn't compile:

```
// error: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate.
let result = albums.flatMap {
    print($0 as Any)
    return $0
}
```

But these do:

```
// explicitly annotate [ElementOfResult] to be [String] – thus ElementOfResult == String.
let result: [String] = albums.flatMap {
    print($0 as Any)
    return $0
}
```

```
// explicitly annotate ElementOfResult? to be String? – thus ElementOfResult == String.
let result = albums.flatMap { element -> String? in
    print(element as Any)
    return element
}
```

Comment: Perhaps emphasize that the return type is inferred automatically for *single-expression closures.* `albums.flatMap { e in print(e); return e }` does not compile.

Comment: While burdensome and surprising, it appears from the bug report discussion that this is actually not a bug!

Comment: @matt Yup, it's just a *feature* to keep your compile times down :) But completely surprising given the sheer list of other amazing things that the type checker is already able to do.

Comment: The other thing worth noting, which may address the OP's point of confusion, is that `flatMap` filters the collection such that nil elements in the original collection don't appear in the output collection. That is, `["a", "b", nil, "c", nil].flatMap { $0 }` takes an array whose type is implicitly `[String?]` (because it contains nils) and produces `["a", "b", "c"]`, whose type is guaranteed to be `[String]` because it prevents nil elements from occurring in the output.

Comment: @rickster I assumed that OP was solely asking about type inference, rather than the actual implementation of `flatMap(_:)` – although I'm less sure since his last edit to the question. In any case, I've gone ahead and added a paragraph about the implementation – thanks for raising it :)

Comment: @rickster OT but it seems that flatMap *not always* filters out nil's  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214880/flatmap-does-not-filter-out-nil-when-elementofresult-is-inferred-to-be-optional not sure yet if it's a bug or a feature.

Comment: @MaximVeksler `flatMap` does two completely (?) unrelated things — I've always hated that. It either (1) flattens an array of arrays into a single array, or (2) safe-unwraps an array of Optionals, eliminating any `nil` elements.

Comment: Thanks @matt now it finally starts to make sense https://gist.github.com/maximveksler/0afaddcd2c3d6554db572894c20ccdaf

Comment: @MaximVeksler Right. See also the discussion in my book http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_array_enumeration_and_transformation Your use of two chained flatmaps with different meanings is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Hamish can you please provide further information on the claim that "therefore ElementOfResult? == String?. There's no need for optional promotion here, so ElementOfResult can be inferred to be String." I can't seem to find any documentation that this is indeed what the compiler does when 2 types func foo<A, B>(closure: A -> B?) -> [B] and A is String? so B can become [String]. I'm not sure that this is the only thing that is going on to make this work.

Comment: @MaximVeksler I'm not quite sure I follow, what else would you expect `B` to become in the example you give? If you're interested in the nitty-gritty details of the type checker, you can take a look at the [Type Checker Design and Implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/TypeChecker.rst) documentation. From what I understand (the documentation isn't terribly clear about it), the promotion of an optional increases the score of a given solution – therefore a solution that doesn't involve optional promotion will be favoured.

Comment: @Hamish: Please excuse me for pinging you like this (and feel free to simply ignore this), but I would like to invite you to have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158798/35991 and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158799/35991. It is about sequences and performance, so you might be interested and perhaps provide valuable feedback.

Comment: @MartinR No problem, I'm always fine with being pinged. The two posts certainly look interesting, and I'll try and have a look at them later today/tomorrow :)