# SwiftUI: Can't call .frame inside ForEach loop

Tags: layout, foreach, swiftui

TL;DR: How does one modify content inside a `ForEach` structure?

The following is a self-contained Playground, in which the call to `frame()` is OK in a plain `body` method, but is a syntax error when wrapped in a `ZStack/ForEach` loop.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    init(_ name:String) { self.name = name }
}

let items = [
    Item("a"), Item("b"), Item("c")
]

struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        return Image("imageName")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width:0, height:0)          // This compiles.
    }

   var body2: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(items) { item -> Image in   // Return type required...
            let i = item                        // ...because of this line.
            return Image(i.name)
                    .resizable()                // Parens required.
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0) // Compile error.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the line `let i = item`. It is standing in for code in my app that performs some calculations. The fact that the `ForEach` closure is not a *single expression* caused the compiler to complain

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate.

which motivated my adding the return type. But *that* brings about the topic of this question, the compiler error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'some View' to return type 'Image'

It appears that the return value of the `frame()` call is not an `Image` but a `ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.Image, SwiftUI._FrameLayout>`.

I have discovered (thanks to commenters!) I can get around this by (somehow) reducing the `ForEach` closure to a single expression, which renders inferrable the return type, which I can then remove. Is this my only recourse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this may just be a limitation of Swift, analogous to or part of this type-inference issue: [Why can't the Swift compiler infer this closure's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534207/why-cant-the-swift-compiler-infer-this-closures-type)

My workaround has been to add functionality to the `Item` struct. Now every calculation needed inside the `ForEach` closure is provided by the `item` instance, in-line to the `Image` initializer, like this:

```
var body3: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(items) { item in        // No return type specified.

            // let (width, height) = ...    // Remove pre-calculations that
                                            // confused the compiler.
            Image(item.name)
                .resizable()
                .frame(
                    width : item.width,     // All needed data are
                    height: item.height     // provided in closure param.
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will grant that this is more idiomatically functional, though I prefer the clarity of a few well-chosen assignments preceding the call. (If the calculations for the assignments are side-effect-free, then it is essentially SSA-style, which should pass the FP smell test.)

So I call this an “answer”, even a “solution”, although I can still whinge about the unhelpful error messages. But that is a known issue, and smarter people than me are already on that.

Answer (score 0):

Now the mesh, I'll have to think about. But getting that first error to go away requires conforming **Item** with identifiable.

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  var name: String
  var size: CGSize = .zero
}
```

I also had to write a custom modifier for using the item to create a frame. We'll likely want to use CGRect for the mesh creation, have some way to mess with the origin of the image.

```
extension View {
  func frame(with size: CGSize) -> some View {
    frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
  }
}
```

Then your body will look something like this.

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    ForEach(items) { item in
      Image(item.name).resizable().frame(with: item.size)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Items are already Identifiable. If they are not, you get a completely different compile error three lines earlier. I forgot to mention the View extension I was using, similar to yours; I updated the question. I left out the origin-shifting to simplify the question. Removing the `-> Image` from the closure's signature (as you did) brings up another error: "Unable to infer complex closure return type", even *without* the troublesome call to `frame`. Also I notice you omitted the parens from your call to `resizable`. In short, I don't think your answer will compile.

Comment: I duplicated my problem in a Playground and edited the question to provide the code. Removed the irrelevant extension. I can confirm that 1) parens are required in the call to `resizable`, and that 2) the compile error persists. However, see my response to @Asperi.

Comment: Your code and mine differ in the closure's return type, and your version (omitting the return type) appeases the compiler *in the Playground* but not my original code. So you're vindicated. And this should be a good clue.

Comment: I think to fix the inference of the item type, you'll just need to add explicit typing to your Item array. let items: [Item] = [....]

Comment: See further comments to @Asperi. Thanks for motivating me to use a Playground.

Answer (score 0):

This is here

```
ForEach(items) { item -> Image in
```

you explicitly specify that closure returns `Image`, but `frame` returns `some View`, so type mismatch and compiler error.

Use just as below and it will work

```
ForEach(items) { item in
```

Comment: I understand the type mismatch. If I take your suggestion and remove the return type *in my actual code* I get the error "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate". But... your suggestion *does* stop the error in the (simplified) Playground example. So now I have to figure out what's different.

Comment: I have re-re-edited the question to focus on what I have found: the compiler's problem in inferring return types when there is more than a single expression. So there is a workaround: rewrite the code to avoid multi-expression bodies. Maybe that is sufficient.