# Can we avoid reduce the Swift verbosity further as we could in Kotlin?

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Kotlin, we could create a scope function as below.

```
    inline fun <R> run(block: () -> R): R {
        return block()
    }
```

We could use it as below to choice which view to show.

```
    run {
        if (choice) viewOne else viewTwo
    }?.show()
```

In Swift, we could also declare as below

```
    @inline(__always) func run<R>(block: () -> R) -> R {
        return block()
    }
```

However, when we use it, it has to be really verbose as below.

```
    run { () -> View? in     // Need to explicitly show `View is return
        if choice {
            return viewOne   // Need to explicitly return
        } else {
            return viewTwo   // Need to explicitly return
        }
    }?.show()
```

Is there anywhere we could reduce the verbosity of Swift that I'm not aware, that it looks more concise? (matching closer to Kotlin)

**UPDATE**

Show entire code

```
@inline(__always) func run<R>(block: () -> R) -> R {
    return block()
}

class View {
    func show() {print("A")}
}

let viewOne: View = View()
let viewTwo: View = View()

var choice = true

run { () -> View in
    return choice ? viewOne : viewTwo
}.show()
```

Comment: Where did you declare that func, in what scope? I cannot compile your code in a playground. Btw the body of your closure can definitely be simplified to `return choice ? viewOne : viewTwo`.

Comment: Nice one on ternary. I forgot about that, after using Kotlin for awhile as it's not available on Kotlin. As for the `run` it is not scope. It is declare as global function.

Comment: It can't be a global func, that produces several compiler errors, including _"Global function cannot return 'Self'"._ Also in your question, the function declaration shows `let`, not `run` - not that the function name would make a difference regarding the type issues.

Comment: Hi @DávidPásztor, I have updated with the entire code that compiles on playground

Comment: Ops, I show the wrong one. Let me update with `run` instead. Sorry!

Comment: “Need to explicitly ... ” – No, `run { choice ? viewOne : viewTwo }.show()` compiles without problems.

Comment: Nice!! Looks like it can only be done with ternary. If the normal if-else, it can't. Is that correct?

Comment: In another word, if it is more than one line, then we have to have `() -> View in` there, correct?

Comment: @Elye: The return type can be inferred from a single-expression closure, or from the context. Compare [Why can't the Swift compiler infer this closure's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42534207/1187415).

Comment: Isn’t the run function redundant in either language? Just wrap the ternary in parentheses. In Kotlin, if/else is a ternary expression.

Comment: This `{ choice ? viewOne : viewTwo }.show()` doesn't work. This works `run { choice ? viewOne : viewTwo }.show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is that the compiler cannot infer the return type of multi-line closures. However, you can easily reduce your closure to a single line using the ternary operator instead of an `if-else`. This way you can get rid of both the `return` statements and the type annotation.

```
run { choice ? viewOne : viewTwo }.show()
```