# "Cannot convert return expression" in flatMap with a meaningless expression inside

Tags: arrays, swift, flatmap

I was examining `.lazy` for high order functions and have got some interesting compile errors related to flatMap function (and possibly others)

**Examples**

```
 
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

array
    .flatMap {
        print("DD")
        return $0 // Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'String?'
    }
    .forEach {
        print("SS")
        print($0)
}
```

**Commenting out a bit**

```
 
array
    .flatMap {
//        print("DD")
        return $0
    }
    .forEach {
        print("SS")
        print($0)
}
```

**And everything works.. even more interesting example**

```
 
array
    .flatMap {
        let z = $0
        return $0  // Or return z - all is the same "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'String?'"
    }
    .forEach {
        print("SS")
        print($0)
}
```

What could cause that behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `flatMap(_:)` method on `Sequence` currently (as of Swift 4) has two different meanings:

- It can take a transform closure that returns an optional `T?`, and it will return a `[T]`, filtering out the `nil` results (this overload [is to be renamed](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md) to `compactMap(_:)` in a future version).

  ```
  public func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?
  ) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
  ```
- It can take a transform closure that returns a `Sequence`, and it will return an array containing the concatenation of all the resulting sequences.

  ```
  public func flatMap<SegmentOfResult : Sequence>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult
  ) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Element]
  ```

Now, in Swift 4, `String` became a `RangeReplaceableCollection` (and therefore a `Sequence`). So Swift 3 code that did this:

```
// returns ["foo"], as using the `nil` filtering flatMap, the elements in the closure
// are implicitly promoted to optional strings.
["foo"].flatMap { $0 }
```

now does this:

```
// returns ["f", "o", "o"], a [Character], as using the Sequence concatenation flatMap,
// as String is now a Sequence (compiler favours this overload as it avoids the implicit
// conversion from String to String?)
["foo"].flatMap { $0 }
```

To preserve source compatibility, specialised `flatMap` overloads [were added](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/128092a7d60b57b8e6d69c8bda48f413b3d418b1/stdlib/public/core/StringRangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb#L418) for strings:

> ```
> //===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
> // The following overloads of flatMap are carefully crafted to allow the code
> // like the following:
> //   ["hello"].flatMap { $0 }
> // return an array of strings without any type context in Swift 3 mode, at the
> // same time allowing the following code snippet to compile:
> //   [0, 1].flatMap { x in
> //     if String(x) == "foo" { return "bar" } else { return nil }
> //   }
> // Note that the second overload is declared on a more specific protocol.
> // See: test/stdlib/StringFlatMap.swift for tests.
> extension Sequence {
>   @_inlineable // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
>   @available(swift, obsoleted: 4)
>   public func flatMap(
>     _ transform: (Element) throws -> String
>   ) rethrows -> [String] {
>     return try map(transform)
>   }
> }
>
> extension Collection {
>   @_inlineable // FIXME(sil-serialize-all)
>   public func flatMap(
>     _ transform: (Element) throws -> String?
>   ) rethrows -> [String] {
>     return try _flatMap(transform)
>   }
> }
> ```

Such that the above usage would still return a `[String]` in Swift 3 compatibility mode, but a `[Character]` in Swift 4.

So, why does

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

array
    .flatMap {
        print("DD")
        return $0 // Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'String?'
    }
    .forEach {
        print("SS")
        print($0)
    }
```

tell you that the closure should return a `String?`?

Well, Swift currently doesn't infer parameter and return types for multi-statement closures (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213785/2976878) for more info). So the `flatMap(_:)` overloads where the closure returns either a generic `T?` or a generic `S : Sequence` aren't eligible to be called without explicit type annotations, as they would require type inference to satisfy the generic placeholders.

Thus, the only overload that is eligible, is the special `String` source compatibility one, so the compiler is expecting the closure to return a `String?`.

To fix this, you can explicitly annotate the return type of the closure:

```
array
  .flatMap { i -> Int? in
    print("DD")
    return i
  }
  .forEach {
    print("SS")
    print($0)
  }
```

But if you're not actually using the optional filtering functionality of this `flatMap(_:)` overload in your real code, you should use `map(_:)` instead.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I was using optional filtering functionality of `flatMap(_:)` in the real code. I have just stripped some code to show the issue without not closely related to the issue parts..

Answer (score 4):

`flatMap` can have different meanings depending on the context. You might tell the compiler more precisely which one you are intending to use.

[image]

---

The two usual purposes to apply `flatMap` to an array which the compiler can infer is to

- flatten nested arrays

  ```
  let array = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
  let flattened = array.flatMap{$0}
  print(flattened) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  ```
- map to another type and filter optionals

  ```
  let array = ["1", "a", "2", "3", "b", "4", "5", "6"]
  let flattened = array.flatMap{ Int($0) }
  print(flattened) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  ```

Comment: Yep, I didn't think about specifying that and after I just added `(num) -> Int? in` everything works as expected. Thank you :)