# why does guard break type inference?

Tags: ios, swift, type-inference, swift-playground

I have met a problem like what title has described: the guard statement breaks type inference for some reason. I have created a `Playground` project to play around.

Here are some boilerplate code for setup:

```
import Foundation

struct Model: Decodable {
    var i: String
}

let jsonString = """
{
    "i": "yes"
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
let theModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: jsonData!)

struct Response<T> {
    var decodedData: T?
}

enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure
}

struct Client {
    static let shared = Client()
    private init() {}

    func execute<T: Decodable>(completion: (Response<T>) -> ()) {
        let decodedData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData!)
        completion(Response(decodedData: decodedData))
    }
}
```

Here's the problem:

```
struct ServicesA {
    func loadSomething(completion: (Result<Model>) -> ()) {
        Client.shared.execute { result in      // error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
            guard let decodedData = result.decodedData else { return }
            completion(Result.success(decodedData))
        }
    }
}

struct ServicesB {
    func loadSomething(completion: (Result<Model>) -> ()) {
        Client.shared.execute { result in
            completion(Result.success(result.decodedData!))
        }
    }
}
```

`ServicesA` breaks whereas `ServicesB` compiles.

As what you can see, the only difference is `guard let decodedData = result.decodedData else { return }`. It breaks the type inference so that the `Client.shared.execute` function complains that the `T` can't be inferred.

I wonder why would this happen and what's the most appropriate way to deal with this issue.

Comment: `guard let decodedData = data else { return }` should be `guard let decodedData = result.decodedData else { return }`

Comment: yes, that was what I was just typing :)

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42213656/2976878 – closures only participate in type inference when they contain a single statement.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yeah thanks, that was a typo when I am editing into stackoverflow. But my program was in the right format. Just edited my question.

Comment: @TonyLin Check my answer it will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR; single line closure compilation is different from multi line

Long answer: Let’s forget single line closures for sometime. When we write generic function accepting a generic as argument type and then call this function, compiler needs to know at time of invocation about what’s the type of function needed i.e. the type of its argument. Now consider this argument is a closure. Again compiler needs to know what’s the type of closure (function signature) at time of invocation. This info should be available in the signature of the closure (i.e. argument and return type), compiler doesn’t worry (and rightly so) about the body of the closure. So Service A is behaving perfectly as expected from compiler i.e. the closure signature doesn’t give any clue of its type.

Now comes in single line closure.  Swift compiler has a built in type inference optimisation for single line closures only. When you write single line closure, compiler first kicks in its type inference and try to figure out about the closure including its return type etc from its only single line of body . This type inference kicks in for single line closures (with or without the context of generics). 
This type inference is the reason that your service B works

So I’ll rephrase the question as “Why does the type inference works for single line closures?” because that’s an extra feature provided by Swift for single line closures only. As soon as you move to multi line closure (its not guard statement specific, same will happen if you put print(“hello world”) as well), this type inference is no more available. Though there may be other type inference checks available for multi line closures.

What you can do is just provide the Type info in closure signature 
i.e (result: Response< Model >)

Comment: Your answer is better-worded than mine, but you should write "statement", not "line".  Swift statements may be broken up across lines.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler only infers closure return types when there is a single statement in the closure.

```
let x = {
    return 1
}()

                // x == Int(1)

let y = {       // error: unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
    print("hi")
    return 2
}()
```

https://forums.swift.org/t/problems-with-closure-type-inference/11859/2

Comment: This is very interesting, but the error seems to be different to mine. They seem complaining about different thing?

Comment: Yours involves generics, and I guess the compiler is complaining about that first.

Comment: actually this is the correct answer, could you provide any reference?

Comment: I think I saw this as a comment on the official Swift Forums.  I'll try and dig up a link.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are referencing `data` variable but the compiler doesn't know what type is this (because it is a Generic). Try this:

```
struct ServicesA {
    func loadSomething<T:Model>(completion:(Result<T>) -> ()) {
        Client.shared.execute { result:Response<T> in
            guard let decodedData = result.decodedData else { return }
            completion(Result.success(decodedData))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain why `ServicesB` won't have this issue if I don't cast the type?

Comment: @TonyLin Because in `ServicesB` the compiler doesn't need to know the type of `Model` you are using. The type of `Model` will be defined by the users of `ServicesB`, that is, in the implementation, i.e. when you call `loadSomething` and assign `completion`. `ServicesA` is different, here you will need to define `Model` in the implementation too, but the type of `Model` is not transparent for `ServicesA` as you are making a reference to it (the guard).

Comment: why making a reference to it (the guard) will lose the type inference?

Comment: Because you can't infer a type that is defined out of the scope. Here by using Generics you are allowing this type to be defined in another class. Basically the guard is **not** "breaking the type inference", rather `ServicesB` is not trying to infer the type, that is why it works there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type cast it `result` with **Result< Model >** so can compiler know about `T`

```
struct ServicesA {
    func loadSomething(completion:(Result<Model>) -> ()) {
        Client.shared.execute { (result:Response<Model>) in
            guard let data = result.decodedData else {return}
            completion(Result.success(data))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain why I need to cast it when I have the `guard` statement? I don't need to cast it when I don't use `guard` as my example given, namely `ServicesB` class.