# Swift reduce - why is value optional?

Tags: swift, reduce, enumeration

Why is `total` optional on line `return total + 1`?

```
return first.enumerated().reduce(0) { total, letter in
   let index = first.index(first.startIndex, offsetBy: letter.offset)
   if first[index] != second[index]{
       return total + 1
   }
   return total
}
```

> Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of
>   type'Int'   Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional
>   value contains 'nil'   Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if
>   the optional value contains 'nil'

So this fixes it:

```
return first.enumerated().reduce(0) { total, letter in
   let index = first.index(first.startIndex, offsetBy: letter.offset)
   if first[index] != second[index]{
       return total! + 1
   }
   return total
}
```

If I break it down the change happens on adding `let index`....

OK - This returns the total count of first and total is not optional:

```
return first.reduce(0) { total, letter in
    return total + 1
}
```

OK - This enumerated and total is not optional:

```
return first.enumerated().reduce(0) { total, letter in
    return total + 1
}
```

ERROR - This gets a compile error that total is optional

```
return first.enumerated().reduce(0) { total, letter in
    let index = first.index(first.startIndex, offsetBy: letter.offset)
    return total + 1
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `first`? Where are you writing this code?

Comment: Both first and second are `String`s

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? I would guess that the return type of the function you're within is optional, and therefore because the [bodies of multi-statement closures don't participate in type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213785/2976878), the compiler is assuming that the `Result` placeholder binds exactly to the return type.

Comment: I assume you are writing this `return` statement in a function. What does the function return?

Comment: @Sweeper you're right - I'm writing this function inside another function that returns an optional, but it doesn't make sense to me that `total` isn't optional until I add `let index` ...

Comment: Note also that your code (unless I am mistaken) exhibits undefined behavior: `index` in an index into the first string and must not be used as subscript into a different string. – Btw, if the purpose is to count the number of distinct characters of two strings: there are simpler solutions.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the purpose is to count the number of distinct characters of two strings. `index` seems to be working for both `first` and `second`. I haven't seen an error about using a subscript to a different string. I'm trying to understand why `total` would change from non-optional to optional depending on if I add more code to the closure or not.

Comment: As @Hamish said above: Type inference in closures is different in single-statement and multi-statement closures. – Btw, another “fix” seems to be `return first.enumerated().reduce(Int(0)) { ... }`

Comment: Try your code with `let first = ""; let second = "abc"` – You'll get a “Fatal error: String index range is out of bounds”

Comment: @MartinR true! I have a guard that checks for equal counts. :) When you say there are simpler solutions are you thinking to use sets?

Comment: Those two strings *have* the same count (three). – `return zip(first, second).filter(!=).count` would be a simple solution equivalent to your code.

Comment: oh! hmm so what makes that String index range is out of bounds? Is that because the smilies are math-based?

Comment: @Turnipdabeets that's because an emoji character can not be represented by a single byte. try `"".utf8.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to get this result at all (as far as I can tell), the enclosing function must return an `Int?`. The implication is that `reduce` can return an optional.  Absent the conditional, the compiler can determine that `reduce` will never return nil, i.e., `total` is never nil.  So, the compiler infers that the return type of the closure is `Int`. The compiler appears to be entangling type inferencing for the `reduce` closure and `total`. Once you add the conditional, the compiler is incapable of determining whether the `reduce` will return nil or not.  Now when it unnecessarily infers the type for `total` it gets it wrong.

To me this looks like a case of Swift type inferencing gone astray.  Clearly, `total` is never nil based on the documentation of `enumerated`.

If you modify the code slightly you get the expected result:

```
   return first.enumerated().reduce(0) { (total: Int, letter) in
       let index = first.index(first.startIndex, offsetBy: letter.offset)
       if first[index] != second[index]{
          return total + 1
       }
       return total
   }
```

Swift makes a lot of type inferences and it is really great because I get strong typing while retaining many of the benefits of a dynamic language. In my experience, however, swift's inferences can be mystifying sometimes. It handles arcane situations with ease and stumbles over something I think is obvious.

It looks like a bug to me.