# Combine weird compile error after placing a print statement in a flatMap operator closure

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have the following method (named: `stories`) from Combine's book by Ray Wenderlich that fetches stories from [Hacker News Public API](https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/) as follows:

Model Object:

```
public struct Story: Codable {
  public let id: Int
  public let title: String
  public let by: String
 public let time: TimeInterval
 public let url: String
}

extension Story: Comparable {
  public static func < (lhs: Story, rhs: Story) -> Bool {
  return lhs.time > rhs.time
  }
}

extension Story: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
   public var debugDescription: String {
   return "\n\(title)\nby \(by)\n\(url)\n-----"
  }
}
```

API Struct:

```
struct API {
  enum Error: LocalizedError {
   case addressUnreachable(URL)
   case invalidResponse

var errorDescription: String? {
  switch self {
  case .invalidResponse: return "The server responded with garbage."
  case .addressUnreachable(let url): return "\(url.absoluteString) is unreachable."
    }
   }
 }

enum EndPoint {
   static let baseURL = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/")!

   case stories
   case story(Int)

   var url: URL {
  switch self {
  case .stories:
    return EndPoint.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("newstories.json")
  case .story(let id):
    return EndPoint.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("item/\(id).json")
     }
   }
 }


var maxStories = 10


private let decoder = JSONDecoder()
private let apiQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "API", qos: .default, attributes: .concurrent)

func story(id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Story, Error> {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: EndPoint.story(id).url)
        .receive(on: apiQueue)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: Story.self, decoder: decoder)
        .catch{ _ in Empty<Story, Error>() }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func mergedStories(ids storyIDs: [Int]) -> AnyPublisher<Story, Error> {
    let storyIDs = Array(storyIDs.prefix(maxStories))
    precondition(!storyIDs.isEmpty)
    let initialPublisher = story(id: storyIDs[0])
    let remainder = Array(storyIDs.dropFirst())
    return remainder.reduce(initialPublisher) { combined, id in //Swift's reduce method
        combined
        .merge(with: story(id: id))
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

func stories() -> AnyPublisher<[Story], Error> {
    URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: EndPoint.stories.url)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: [Int].self, decoder: decoder)
        .mapError { error -> API.Error in
            switch error {
            case is URLError:
                return Error.addressUnreachable(EndPoint.stories.url)
            default:
                return Error.invalidResponse
            }
    }
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    .flatMap { storyIDs in
        print("StoryIDs are \(storyIDs)") //the print statement that causes the error
       return self.mergedStories(ids: storyIDs)
    }
    .scan([]) { stories, story -> [Story] in
        stories + [story] //<--- Error fires here
    }
    .map { $0.sorted() }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

Consumer Code:

```
let api = API()
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
api.stories()
.sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
      receiveValue: { print($0) })
.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

The method works perfectly without putting in the `print("storyIDs are \(storyIDs)")` statement, once this print statement is placed, a weird compiler error fires at the line: `stories + [story]`  which says:

> `'[Any]' is not convertible to 'Array<Story>'`

I don't know what does this misleading error mean in such case ?

Comment: Rather a lot here depends on methods and types you have not shown us.

Comment: Multiline closures do not take part in type inference, so making the closure to `flatMap` a multiline one, you are somehow causing it to be unable to infer the type parameters of `flatMap`. If you just want to print the values you receive, you can call `.print()`.

Comment: I have added missing parts, if you copy-paste the code it works without the that buggy print statement. please remove the downvote.

Comment: @Sweeper I know about the .print() operator, but what if I need to custom print an object inside one of the operator closures of Combine, what should I do to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Multi-statement closures do not take part in type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213656/how-flatmap-api-contract-transforms-optional-input-to-non-optional-result/42213785#42213785), so making the closure to flatMap a multi-statement one, you are somehow causing it to incorrectly infer the type parameters of `scan`. You can provide the types it needs by writing them out in the closure:

```
.flatMap { storyIDs -> AnyPublisher<Story, API.Error> in
    print("StoryIDs are \(storyIDs)")
   return self.mergedStories(ids: storyIDs)
}
```

If you just want to print the values you receive, you can call `.print()` as well.

Update:

I played around with this a bit more, and I found that if you put everything before `scan` into a `let` constant, and call `scan` on that constant, the error moves to somewhere else:

```
let pub = URLSession.shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: EndPoint.stories.url)
    .map(\.data)
    .decode(type: [Int].self, decoder: decoder) //<--- Error fires here now!
    .mapError { error -> API.Error in
        switch error {
        case is URLError:
            return Error.addressUnreachable(EndPoint.stories.url)
        default:
            return Error.invalidResponse
        }
}
.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
.flatMap { storyIDs in
    print("StoryIDs are \(storyIDs)")
   return self.mergedStories(ids: storyIDs)
}

return pub.scan([]) { stories, story -> [Story] in
    stories + [story]
}
.map { $0.sorted() }
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

> Instance method 'decode(type:decoder:)' requires the types 'URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output' (aka '(data: Data, response: URLResponse)') and 'JSONDecoder.Input' (aka 'Data') be equivalent

This time, it caused `decode`'s type arguments to be inferred wrongly. The original error at `scan` disappeared because now the compiler knows that `pub` has a definite type, though it had (incorrectly) found an error somewhere else before it could determine the type of `pub`.

Following this pattern, I made another temporary `let` constant:

```
let pub1 = URLSession.shared
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: EndPoint.stories.url)
    .map(\.data)
let pub2 = pub1
    .decode(type: [Int].self, decoder: decoder)
    .mapError { error -> API.Error in
        switch error {
        case is URLError:
            return Error.addressUnreachable(EndPoint.stories.url)
        default:
            return Error.invalidResponse
        }
}
.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
.flatMap { storyIDs in
    print("StoryIDs are \(storyIDs)")
   return self.mergedStories(ids: storyIDs)
}

return pub2.scan([]) { stories, story -> [Story] in
    stories + [story]
}
.map { $0.sorted() }
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Finally, the compiler shows a useful message at `storyIDs in`, which leads use to the solution at the start of the answer:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

It even tells us what type we should insert!

Comment: excellent answer. I don't know why's the downvote for my question.

Comment: @JAHelia I could understand the downvote if it’s before the edit (is it?), as you didn’t provide all the required info. So I guess it’s just that the downvoter hasn’t seen the edit yet, maybe.

Comment: @JAHelia I've found some more insight on this. See the edit. The Swift compiler is weird :-).

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I've got a bug filed on the fact that the compiler is able to tell us what type to insert while claiming at the same time that it cannot infer the type: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5735